# Не получается создать список списков

Tags: php

Не получается создать список списков. Я так понимаю это делается через массивы?
Вот например если основные данные в каталоге - это мастера и их товары. Количество мастеров и товаров не ограничено может быть, но вы точно знаете, что каждый товар изготавливает только один мастер.

Как создать **единственный** массив $data, и придумать его структуру таким образом, чтобы можно было удобно хранить информацию по мастерам и их товарам?

Для товара нужно хранить следующую информацию: Наименование товара, Цена, Мастер
О мастере нужно хранить следующую информацию о нем: Никнейм, Город, Доставка (Да/Нет)

Как это сделать, если учесть, что набор полей в будущем может расширяться.

Заполните этот массив следующими данными
[image: Мастера]

Я новичок в программировании, я пробовал создать массив $data, но как вложить в этот массив ещё один массив?

Comment: http://www.php.su/learnphp/datatypes/?array тут с примерами все есть , просто элементами массива будут другие массивы

Comment: Не получается. Я создаю Массив с товаром и мастерами, но этот массив перезаписывается. Как можно сделать так что бы был один всего массив и при этом там была информацияпо мастерам и их товарам?

Answer (score 0):

`$masters = массив с мастерами`;
`$goods = массив с товарами`;

```
$goodsByMasters = [];
foreach ($masters as $master) {
    foreach ($goods as $good) {
        if (isset($goodsByMasters[$master->getId()])) {
             $goodsByMasters[$master->getId()]['goods'][] = $good;
        } else {
             $goodsByMasters[$master->getId()] = [
                 'master' => $master,
                 'goods' => [
                     $good
                 ]
             ];
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Тоже делаю этот квест handmade для qsoft, нигде не нашел ответа.
Но методом проб и ошибок, тестирование приняло следующий ответ:

```
$data = [
        'Чебурашка' => ['Челябинск', 'нет', []],
        'Nick' => ['Москва', 'да', ['Бетон' => 100, 'Герб' => 150, ]],
        'Black' => ['Казань', 'нет', ['Квадрат' => 799, ]],
];
```